# Median adjusted normalization used in quantitative proteomics

Tags: normalization

> [Cross-posted from Biostar](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/8710/how-to-calculate-fold-change-and-its-significance-in-quantitative-proteomics)

I'm stuck in a step for calculating Normalized intensity ratio for i-TRAQ reporter ions, used in quantitative proteomics.

Here's the [worked out example](http://proteome-software.wikispaces.com/FAQ+-+Quantitation+and+Scaffold+Qplus) of how it's calculated and the description is as follows.

Medain adjusted normalization is used in quantitative proteomics. The reporter ion intensities from all the identified peptide spectra are used to calculate non-normalized reporter ion ratios. These ratios are then used to compute the media adjusted normalized intensities. For example, all the reporter ion intensities are multiplied by their respective median non-normalized ratio. Once these median adjusted normalized intensities are calculated, new ratios are computed.

The first step of calculating Non-Normalized Ratios is just dividing 734,442,619,992 by the first or 'reference' channel value i.e.734 which yields Non-Normalized Ratios 1.00,0.60,0.84,1.35.

I didn't understand how the "Median adjusted Normalized Intensity" was calculated in the second step. The third step is obvious again, divide the Median adjusted Normalized Intensity values by 734 which gives the Normalized Intensity Ratios 1.00,0.94,0.91,1.42

Can someone please explain the second step?

Comment: I believe the normalization in proteomics is similar to microarray quantile normalization. However, I find your description a bit hard to understand. Could you pls make it a bit general: as in what are your rows and columns (in an excel or csv file) and any other details (not necessarily the numbers but what are your data?).

Comment: Likely divide by median value, or alternatively in log scales, subtract the median log ratio.